# Tricky change-of-basis transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, linear-transformations

I have absolutely no idea what to do here because of the $\sin(x).$

Let $V = \text{Span}\left\{x, x^3, \sin(x) \right\}$, and consider the basis for $V$ given by $\beta = \left\{x-2x^3, x^3+\sin(x), -3x^3 \right\}$.  Define the transformation $T: V \rightarrow M_{2 \times 2}$ by
$$T(ax+bx^3+c\sin(x)) = \begin{bmatrix} a+b & c-b \\ c & -a \end{bmatrix}$$
Consider the basis of $M_{2 \times 2}$ given by 
$C = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}.$

Find the matrix A such that for all $\vec{v} \in V$
$$A[\vec{v}]_{\beta} = [T(\vec{v})]_{C}$$

Comment: So would it be represented as a matrix like a polynomial vector space?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm also confused on how to do that.  How would I represent $[\vec{v}]_{\beta}$ if the basis is in $\mathbb{R^3}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really care what the underlying vector spaces may be, and I suspect that's the point of the problem. When you have a linear transformation from $X$ to $Y$, and you have a basis $\{ x_{j} \}_{j=1}^{J}$ of $X$ and a basis $\{ y_{k} \}_{k=1}^{K}$ of $Y$, then all you have to know is a tabulation of the numbers $a_{j,k}$ such that
$$
                    Tx_{1} = a_{1,1}y_1+a_{2,1}y_2+\cdots+a_{K,2}y_K,\\
                    Tx_{2} = a_{1,2}y_1+a_{2,2}y_2+\cdots+a_{K,2}y_K,\\
                      \vdots \\
                    Tx_{J} = a_{1,J}y_1+a_{2,J}y_2+\cdots+a_{K,J}y_K
$$
Then $T$ is represented by $[a_{j,k}]$ when viewed with respect to these bases. So, $V$ has a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ where $v_1=x$, $v_2=x^{3}$, $v_3=\sin(x)$ and $M_{2\times 2}$ is given the basis $C=\{ m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4\}$. By definition of $T$ and $\{ m_j \}$,
$$
\begin{align}
     Tx & = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right] = -m_2,\\
     Tx^{3} & = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right] = \frac{1}{2}(m_1-m_2)+m_4 \\
    T\sin(x) & = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right] = m_3-m_4
\end{align}
$$
So the matrix $A$ that defines $T$ from basis $\{ v_j\}$ to basis $\{ m_k\}$ is
$$
            A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
                                     -1 & -1/2 & 0 \\
                                     0 & 0 & 1 \\
                                     0 & 1 & -1 \end{array}\right]
$$